# How to get json data using c#?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization, deserialization

```
string json string = {\"GetMyClassListResult\":{\"MyClassList\":[{\"Id\":1,\"Amount\":\"5,00\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Amount\":\"10,00\"},{\"Id\":3,\"Amount\":\"20,00\"},{\"Id\":4,\"Amount\":\"25,00\"}],\"ReturnValues\":{\"ErrorCode\":1,\"ErrorDescription\":\"Successful\"}}}
```

How do  get "Id":1" and "Amount":"5,00" ?

Comment: You could start by formatting your Json so we can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would need to declare a class as following.

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; } 
}
```

and then, you can do the following in your method

```
var Jsonobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(Jsonobj["GetMyClassListResult"]["MyClassList"].ToString()).ToList<MyClass>();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @sunayyildiz Do you have `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Thanks Anu,    RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
      
            var result2 = obj.GetCardTaskListResult.CardTaskList.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Amount = p.Amount}).ToArray();
that code is good work :)

Answer (score 1):

Combining the excellent **Json.NET** package with **LINQ** you could use:

```
var result = JObject.Parse(json)["GetMyClassListResult"]["MyClassList"]
                    .Select(item => new { Id = item["Id"], Amount = item["Amount"] })
                    .First();
```

`result` has the properties `Id` and `Amount` corresponding to the first item in the JSON array with values `1` and `"5,00"`.

If instead you wanted an array of all items, just replace `First()` with `ToArray()`.

Comment: Hi Jon,                                                                                                              I am insert 
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;   but not working   " .Select()"                                     instead of SelectToken and SelectTokens

Comment: Have you included `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file?

Comment: I am insert  using System.Linq. I want to use  ToList<MyClassList>.. ı am insert my code ;                                                              "List<MyClassList> myClassList = new List<MyClassList>();
  myClassList  = JObject.Parse(responseText)["GetMyClassListResult"]["MyClassList"].Select(item => new { Id = item["Id"], Amount = item["Amount"] }).ToList<MyClassListt>();"   but not working...

Comment: You *could* use `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()`, but this uses an anonymous type so unless you are only going to use the list locally (or you use `dynamic` - but don't) you'll need to create your own type as per Anu's answer.

Comment: Thanks Jon,    RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
      
            var result2 = obj.GetCardTaskListResult.CardTaskList.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Amount = p.Amount}).ToArray();
that code is good work :)

Answer (score 1):

So you have straight json and you're trying to convert it into an object to get some meaningful values?

I *personally* prefer working with classes where I can. I will throw my raw json into a json to C# converter. I like [JsonUtils](http://jsonutils.com) personally. (I have no affiliation, just a great free service.) There are some others out there, but it seems to be the most robust.

If you throw your raw json into there, you get the following classes:

```
public class MyClassList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnValues
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}

public class GetMyClassListResult
{
    public IList<MyClassList> MyClassList { get; set; }
    public ReturnValues ReturnValues { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public GetMyClassListResult GetMyClassListResult { get; set; }
}
```

Alright. Now that we have our models, we can deserialize the json. The most popular library for manipulating json is [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or direct download.

You'll need to add a reference to that dll if you choose to download it; Nuget will auto-reference it when you install it.

At the top of your class file, you'll need to add

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

along with your other `using` statements.

In your method you'll call `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Example>>(json)`, which will give you your collection in POCOs.

Since there is only one object in the collection you can call `.First()` on the collection and then access the two values via the `Id` and `Amount` properties. You will need to make sure that `System.Linq` is in your `using` statements as well.

Full code:

```
var json = @"{\"GetMyClassListResult\":{\"MyClassList\":[{\"Id\":1,\"Amount\":\"5,00\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Amount\":\"10,00\"},{\"Id\":3,\"Amount\":\"20,00\"},{\"Id\":4,\"Amount\":\"25,00\"}],\"ReturnValues\":{\"ErrorCode\":1,\"ErrorDescription\":\"Successful\"}}}";

var collection = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Example>>(json);

var x = collection.First();
var amount = x.Amount;
var id = x.Amount;
```

You're then free to manipulate or work with those variables as you see fit. :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need a class where you will de-serialize  this string to your class object.
you need a class which will contain Id and Amount variable.

after that you can de-serialize this string to the object then you can access any data you want.